# how to get query string from a javax.persistence.Query?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, query-string

Maybe I am missing something, but I simply want to (in my java program) get the query string from a `javax.persistence.Query` object?
The `Query` object itself doesn't seem to have a method to do that. Also I know that our manager doesn't want us to use Spring framework stuff (for example using their `QueryUtils` class).

Is there not a way to simply get the query string from `javax.persistence.Query` object (Again, in a java program) ?!

Answer (score 7):

no problem.  hibernate:

```
query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString()
```

or eclipselink

`query.unwrap(JpaQuery.class).getDatabaseQuery().getJPQLString(); // doesn't work for CriteriaQuery
query.unwrap(JpaQuery.class).getDatabaseQuery().getSQLString();`

or open JPA

```
query.unwrap(org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.class).getQueryString()
```

...you get the idea....

Answer (score 1):

There is no JPA-standard way, but some implementations have their own methods. For example DataNucleus JPA allows you to do

```
query.toString();
```

Look at the docs of your implementation for how they do it. See also this blog entry
http://antoniogoncalves.org/2012/05/24/how-to-get-the-jpqlsql-string-from-a-criteriaquery-in-jpa/

Comment: This does not return the query string value but translates the object to a string. example "org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl@"

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way in JPA,

If you are using EclipseLink see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_get_the_SQL_for_a_Query.3F

Answer (score 0):

Edit your persistence properties file if JPA is provided by hibernate. Add the below section -

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenJPA I was able to do this:

```
OpenJPAQuery<MyEntity> q = (OpenJPAQuery<MyEntity>) query;
String mySQL = q.getQueryString();
```

The cast to OpenJPAQuery is important because the Query interface does not have the method getQueryString() on it.

The stored parameters are not filled in unfortunately but I'm working on figuring out how to do that myself.